# File/directory search

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Any idea how to easily support file search patterns in your software, like **, *, ?

For example subfolder/**/?svn - search in all levels of subfolder for files/folders ending in "svn" 4 characters in total.

full description: http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/types/fileset.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you load the directory as a directory info e.g.

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(folder);
```

then do a search for files like this

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> fileInfo = directory.GetFiles("*.svn", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

this should get you a list of fileInfo which you can manipulate

to get all subdirectories you can do the same e.g

```
IEnumerable<DirectoryInfo> dirInfo = directory.GetDirectories("*svn", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

anyway that should give a idea of how i'd do it. Also because `fileInfo` and `dirInfo` are IEnumerable you can add linq where queries etc. to filter results

Answer (score 1):

A mix of regex and recursion should do the trick.

Another trick might be to spawn a thread for every folder or set of folders and have the thread proceed checking one more level down. This could be beneficial to speed up the process a bit.

The reason I say this is because that is highly io bound process to check folders etc. So many threads will allow you to submit more disk requests faster thus improving the speed.

Comment: I'm afraid that's way far from being efficient.

Comment: Why is that inefficient? You have to parse strings somehow.

Comment: You can not increase efficiency unless filesystem contents are already indexed. Since this patter spans across sub directories, you will have to Travers them to evaluate the expression.

Comment: FS will usually be indexed, especially on the second run, so creating Regex every time for every pattern (there are lots of them) is way too expensive. I was thinking about translating the subset of the pattern to filesystem query, and then somehow complete filtering. The task seems to be a bit challenging, so I was wondering if there is a solution already. NAnt's DirectoryScanner seems to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound silly, but have you considered downloading the nant source code to see how they did it?

Comment: Yeah, I could probably use their DirectorySearcher class, it does the job.